# POST request doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, http-post

Here is my `prepareForSegue` method

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! AllCommentsViewController
    if segue.identifier == "addComment" {
        if let stringText = commentTF.text {
            vc.CommentsArray.append(stringText)

            let urlString = "http://sekaaleksic.cloudlk.com/api/v1/post/comment/\(postId)/submitComment"

            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: urlString)!)
            let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
            let params = ["comment=\(stringText)"]

            request.HTTPBody = try? NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: [])
            request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
            request.addValue("\(stringText)", forHTTPHeaderField: "comment")
            request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

            let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { data, response, error -> Void in

                print(request.HTTPBody)
                print(params)
                print(error)
                print(response)
                print(data)
            })

            task.resume()

            }

        }
    }
}
```

So, what's the problem?
As you see, my `urlString` is where Wordpress API for submitting a comment. `postId` is an ID of a post.

I should do something like this: `$_POST['comment'] = 'some comment message';`

But this code isn't working (you can check the number of Comments for specific post on [this link][1])

Here is the XCode Log ->

```
["test"]
Optional(<5b22636f 6d6d656e 743d7465 7374225d>)
["comment=test"]
nil
Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x137bd1300> { URL: http://sekaaleksic.cloudlk.com/api/v1/post/comment/1/submitComment } { status code: 200, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = "no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0, no-cache";
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
    "Content-Length" = 70;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    Date = "Wed, 10 Feb 2016 14:00:03 GMT";
    Expires = "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT";
    "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=5, max=700";
    Pragma = "no-cache";
    Server = Apache;
    Vary = "Accept-Encoding";
} })
Optional(<7b227374 61747573 223a6661 6c73652c 22657870 6c61696e 223a2243 6f6d6d65 6e742070 6f737420 69732065 6d707479 227d>)



  [1]: http://sekaaleksic.cloudlk.com/api/v1/post/1/countComments
```

Comment: You never set the body of the request, you have it commented out.

Comment: Not working even when uncommented..

Comment: Well is your php set up to receive the request as JSON?

Comment: In Laravel, Input::get('comment')

Comment: What is the content-type for the response you print out? I've had it still be text/html when it was supposed to be JSON, I fixed this by using `setValue` instead of `addValue`.

Comment: Are you supposed to have the comment in both the headers and parameters?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by the 'code isn't working'? Are you getting an error when the code is run?

Comment: Try this: `let body = "comment=\(stringText)"` and then `request.HTTPBody = body.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF*StringEncoding)`

Comment: Could you add your PHP to your question please?

Comment: Gabriel Jones anwered it clearly and simply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are encoding the JSON wrong.

Make `params` equal to:

```
["comment": stringText]
```

JSON is used to encode dictionaries, not concatenated strings.

Comment: Thank you! I would have never figure that one out!